# jqgrid colModel key

Tags: jqgrid

I'm trying to update rows based on the value of a column that has key: true set, but the column is alphanumeric, here is the grid:

```
jQuery("#list2").jqGrid({
datatype: "local",
colNames:['Col1','Col2', 'Col3'],
colModel:[
    {name:'Col1', width:200, key:true},
    {name:'Col2', width:90},
    {name:'Col3', width:100}
],
rowNum:20,
caption:"Output"
});
```

Below is what I'm doing to test if I can access row data based on the value of Col1, which is a mixture of numbers and letters and between 20 and 32 characters.

```
var blah = jQuery("#list2").getRowData( '23feba2f5258b2bffe0454' );
$("#error").text(JSON.stringify(blah));
```

The above will just print '{}' to the div with id error.
But if you try:

```
var blah = jQuery("#list2").getRowData( '1' );
$("#error").text(JSON.stringify(blah));
```

The object will be printed.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: It's strange that there are no `data` option of jqGrid. .It's unclear how and with which data you fill the grid. Could you include test data which you use to fill the grid? The best if you post all information needed for reproducing of the problem which you describe.